# My SQL Database selecting between 2 dates

Tags: mysql, database

have this on my database

```
InspectionID  Inspection Date OdometerReading Truck Id
     1         2013-04-07       1000              1
     2         2013-04-14       2040              1
     3         2013-04-21       3000              1
    ...          .....          ....
     21         2013-05-23      1000              2
     22         2013-05-30      2000              2
     23         2013-06-07      3000              2
     24        2013-07-14       2040              3
     25         2013-07-21       3000             3
    ...          .....          ....             ....
     30         2014-05-23      15050             3
     34         2014-05-30      16032             1
```

I have selected DateStart: 2013-04-01 and  DateFinished: 2014-06-01 on my datepicker, the query that should be selected is 2013-04-07 and 2014-05-30.

To summarize my question: How could i Select the First and Last Row between the Date Start and DateFinished Query so I can compute the average OdometerReading of each truck_id on a specific time period

Comment: Why don't you use the avg() function on odometer reading field by truck id?

Comment: You should add your current query and show the error your having

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by selecting the Top 1 of table using DESC order and union to the Top 1 of ASC Order...

**EDITED**

```
SELECT Inspectiondate FROM TableName
    ORder By Inspectiondate DESC LIMIT
    UNION
    SELECT Top 1 Inspectiondate FROM TableName
    ORder By Inspectiondate LIMIT 1
```

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1` does not work in MySQL, it needs to be `SELECT ... LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear what your table structure is, or what exactly you are trying to achieve. Based on the above data, it seems that you want to select all rows where `Inspection Date` is between the start and end dates specified.

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE `Inspection Date` BETWEEN '2013-04-01' AND '2014-06-01'
```

Note that BETWEEN is inclusive, so if you had data on '2013-04-01' it would appear in the results.

If you want the average Odometer for each truck, you can achieve this by grouping.

```
SELECT AVG(OdometerReading),TruckId FROM YourTable WHERE `Inspection Date` BETWEEN '2013-04-01' AND '2014-06-01' GROUP BY TruckId
```